# How to filter missing JSON elements in R-script?

Tags: r, json, element

R/JSON newbie.. I am trying to extract details of the various types of monitoring equipment used to measure emissions on power plant stacks (manufacturer, model, type).

This information is contained within the "`monitoringSystems`" element of the JSON object.  However, some of these power plants do not use monitoring equipment on their stacks and there is no "`monitoringSystems`" element.

If I run my script without attempting to filter units without monitoring systems, I get the following error (`locName is an element of monitoringSystems, which doesn't exist for index=3`):

Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 3.
Caused by error in `dplyr::select()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `locName` doesn't exist.

I tried skipping those units without a monitoringSystems element using an 'if exists' function, but I get the following error:

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `response = get_monitor_data(query)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `if (.) ...`:
! the condition has length > 1

The JSON structure is as follows:
`data.monitoringLocations().monitoringSystems().locname,sysID,sysTypeCode`...

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

Helper function to get the json response from the query

```
get_monitor_data <- function(queries) {
  response <- queries %>%
   map(function(query){
     response <- GET(query)
     warn_for_status(response)
     if (response$status_code == 200) {
       mon_json <- content(response, as = "text")
       units_tbl <- mon_json %>%
         enter_object("data") %>%
         spread_all() %>%
         enter_object("monitoringLocations") %>%
         gather_array() %>%
         spread_all() %>%
         
     if(exists("monitoringSystems")) {

         enter_object(monitoringSystems) %>%
         gather_array() %>%
         spread_all() %>%
            
       select(
            LOC_NAME = locName,
        SYS_ID = sysId,
        SYS_TYPE_CODE = sysTypeCode,
        COMPONENT_ID = componentId,
        SERIAL_NUM = serialNum,
        MANUFACTURER = manufacturer,
        MODEL_VERSION = modelVersion,
        COMPONENT_TYPE_CODE = componentTypeCode,
        ACQ_CODE = acqCode,
        BASIS_CODE = basisCode,
        SYS_BEGIN_DATE_HOUR = sysBeginDateHour,
        SYS_END_DATE_HOUR = sysEndDateHour,
        COMPONENT_BEGIN_DATE_HOUR = componentBeginDateHour,
        COMPONENT_END_DATE_HOUR = componentEndDateHour,
        SYSTEM_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = systemTypeDescription,
        SYSTEM_DESIGNATION_CODE_DESC = systemDesignationCodeDesc,
        ACQ_CODE_DESCRIPTION = acqCodeDescription,
        COMPONENT_TYPE_CODE_DESCRIPTION = componentTypeCodeDescription,
        BASIS_CODE_DESC = basisCodeDesc
         )
       }      
     }
    }
   )
}
```

Perform the GET request for each query and pull out the content of the request, and gather the laod dater for each unit.

```
#Pull out the content of the request
responses <- queries %>%
  mutate(
    response = get_monitor_data(query)
    )

#Unnest the data frames from the response
unit_monitor_data <- unnest(responses, cols = c(response))


unit_monitor_data
```